# jQuery doesn't work properly after major renaming

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 2.2.4. Everything was ok until I done a major renaming. I renamed the main object, from actual application name to "app". I also renamed other things, as I was changing my app name.

Unfortunately jQuery (minified) doesn't work properly now . I noticed it 2 days after. I spotted 2 weird errors. For example:

`$('body').on('change','input:not(.error)', function() { });`

When input is changed I get an error "cannot read property test of undefined". jQuery was concatenated with my application file. When I moved jQuery to a separate file I got "uncaught reference error: app is not defined" for that event.

I renamed my main object back from app to something specific, but it didn't have any effect. And development version of jQuery works fine. I can't run a diff, because I changed so many things. Either I will find what causes the issue, or I will have to revert and do everything again.

Does anyone know what might cause jQuery to break? I remind that it only doesn't work on the minified, development version of jQuery.

Comment: Do you have your code you can post in a Stack Snippet?

Comment: I'm thinking that you might have accidentally replaced something in the "minified, development version of jQuery".  Try getting the latest of this again and see if you still have the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really saved me time. I feel so stupid now that I haven't thought of that. Brackets should have an option to exclude files.